# How might I get an element's border color value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, dom

Using `$("#id").css("background-color")` to retrieve an element's background color (or most other CSS attributes) works just fine, but
`$("#id").css("border-color")` returns an empty string.

How can I get the border color value used on the element?

Comment: An explanation is here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html Note it works in IE.

Comment: Tryed the script they give there - got the same result. So apparently it's not a JQuery issue, but a Javascript issue...

Comment: JussiR: right you are! jQuery can't solve everything...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

CSS has "short-hand" properties that allows you to send multiple properties at once. Like `font`, `border`, `background`, etc. Well, the `border-color` CSS property actually sets the 4 properties `border-top-color`, `border-right-color`, `border-bottom-color`, and `border-left-color`.

If you want to get the border-color, you need to specify which side. For instance, to obtain the current value of `border-left-color`, you'd do:

```js
$("#id").css("border-left-color")
```

This should work just fine since it seems as you're expecting that every side has the same color.

Comment: Sounds logical, but it also returns empty string (null with chrome).

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong. It's border-left-color, border-top-color, border-right-color, border-bottom color. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 8):

William was close... The property you're looking for is **border-left-color**, so in full you need

```
$('#ID').css("border-left-color")
```

and to set it

```
$('#ID').css("border-left-color","blue");
```

for example.

Good luck, and hit me back in the comments.

Comment: Great! I think we have the answer, thanks for everone envolved!

Comment: Oh, right. I thought there was a feature to mark accepted answers, but only now realised how to do that.